# ERROR:'Credentials' object has no attribute 'with_subject'

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to use Google Ads API using service account.
The following works:

```py
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials as ServiceAccountCreds

oauth2_client = ServiceAccountCreds.from_service_account_file(
    filename=key_file, subject=developer_account,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"]
)
google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient(login_customer_id=self.login_customer_id, credentials=oauth2_client,
                                    developer_token=self.developer_token)

self.ga_service = self.google_ads_client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v9")
self.ga_serice.search_stream(customer_id=self.client_customer_id, query =  query)
```

I want to to do following with Identity Workload Federation(w/o key):

```py
from google.auth import aws as google_auth_aws
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

credentials = google_auth_aws.Credentials.from_info(json_config_info)  # from workload identity federation
credentials = credentials.with_scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"])
credentials = credentials.with_subject(self.developer_account)
# Build the service object.
self.google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient(login_customer_id=self.login_customer_id, credentials=credentials,
                                    developer_token=self.developer_token)

self.ga_service = self.google_ads_client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v9")
self.ga_service.search_stream(customer_id =self.client_customer_id, query =  self.query)
```

Which throws error:
ERROR:'Credentials' object has no attribute 'with_subject'.

Comment: Are you sure its not credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this method doesn't exist for `google.auth.aws.Credentials`.

Comment: it should for google.auth

Comment: Im using aws.Credentials from here: `https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/google/auth/aws.py`. Can you please navigate if you know.

Comment: I now aws and Google apis are two different systems.  Nothing in that file says it will work with ads api.  your code isnt even setting up a deligation user unless you have added the service account as  a user in your ads account.